# get all fields value from mysql using php

Tags: php, arrays, filter

i want to know how to get all fields value search by array.

i have array that s

my table is

```
  id   content

  1    zahr
  2    hai
   .
   .
   .
  and so on


$a = {2,3,4,5,43,32};

i have to take the contents by this id(from array "a").

i know, i can use "for" loop for getting each element from mysql.

but i would like to use any filters or any predefined function
```

thanks and advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**IN**](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (2,3,4,5,43,32)
```

the statement could be created by using implode like:

```
$myvar = '('.implode(',',$a).')';
```

and then

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN $myvar
```

Comment: hey i am getting empty result if i use array.

i can get if i give input directly like select * from details where id in(1)